# make link text same height as link background

Tags: html, css

Seems simple but I can't seem to do it, I would like to make the text of my link the same height as the background of the link.

```
<a href='link.htm' style='background-color: red; display: block; height: 30px; font-size: 30px;'>Link text</a>
```

The problem is there is always a margin around the text

Comment: what font are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using `text-decoration: underline`. 
If you remove `height: 30px`, the block will rezise to the size of font.

Here are examples: [Width static height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hljn3.png) , [Removed height property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvp0u.png).

Or you can set `text-decoration: none` and then it will fit the block.

It it what you wanted? If not, please provide some screenshots with explanation.

Comment: lamentably no, removing the height did not work. neither did setting text-decoration: none

Answer (score 0):

The font-size doesn't reflect the physical height that the text occupies, you have to account for descenders as well. You could set the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

```
<a href='link.htm' style='background-color: red; display: block; 
height: 30px; font-size: 30px; line-height: 30px;'>Link text</a>
```

(You should use a stylesheet rather than inline styles, although this perhaps is just to demonstrate the issue?)

Setting the line-height does make the height setting redundant for this small example though and, usually, the line-height is larger than the font size, defaulting to roughly 1.2.

Comment: I tried setting the line height, it didn't work :-( yes the inline styling was for the benefit of this example